# Parallel HTTP Requests Deadlock when Run from Dr Racket

Tags: concurrency, racket, mutex, semaphore

I've been trying to write a Racket GUI tool that makes simultaneous HTTP requests across multiple threads and prints progress as it progresses. I decided to use a semaphore to avoid rate limiting and a mutex to manage the counter.

I encountered deadlocks while developing and attempted to isolate the issue. Eventually I realized that I only encounter the issue when running from Dr Racket. When the below code is run from Dr Racket, multiple threads will state they are trying to acquire a lock, but it has not been released, so the program deadlocks. From Emacs it works as expected.

I'm assuming that my code has a concurrency error that I don't understand, which is only presenting itself when run from Dr Racket for some reason. Could anyone help me understand the issue and fix it?

```
#lang racket

(require net/http-easy)
(require rebellion/concurrency/lock)

(define (make-get-request)
  (let* ([url "http://example.com"]
         [response (get url)])
    response))

(define downloader-semaphore (make-semaphore 100))
(define progress-lock (make-lock))
(define progress-counter 0)

(define (download-simple-request index total)
  (call-with-semaphore downloader-semaphore
                        (lambda ()
                          (let ([result (make-get-request)])
                            (printf "Lock about to be acquired at: ~a\n" (current-inexact-milliseconds))
                            (lock-acquire! progress-lock)
                            (printf "Lock acquired at: ~a\n" (current-inexact-milliseconds))
                            (set! progress-counter (add1 progress-counter))
                            (printf "~a/~a\n" progress-counter total)
                            (lock-release! progress-lock)
                            (printf "Lock released at: ~a\n" (current-inexact-milliseconds))
                            result))))

(define (parallel-download num-requests)
  (let* ([total num-requests]
         [channel (make-channel)]
         [threads (for/list ([index (in-range num-requests)])
                    (thread (lambda ()
                              (channel-put channel (download-simple-request index total)))))]
         [results (for/list ([_ (in-range num-requests)])
                    (channel-get channel))])
    results))

(let* ([start-time (current-inexact-milliseconds)]
       [num-requests 100] ; Number of times to hit the URL
       [_ (parallel-download num-requests)]
       [end-time (current-inexact-milliseconds)])
  (printf "STARTING TIME ~a\n" start-time)
  (printf "ENDING TIME ~a\n" end-time)
  (printf "TOTAL TIME ~a\n" (- end-time start-time)))
```